# How to get primitive wrapper classes constructors via reflection?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a new primitive wrapper object via reflection in Java and I struggle to get the constructors of them. I tried to do the same thing with a String class without problems (as a sanity test, I can for example create a String object using constructor that accepts a StringBuilder) Please see the code below:

```
try {
    Constructor<?>[] cons = String.class.getConstructors();
    System.out.println(cons + " / " + cons.length);
    Constructor<String> con = String.class.getConstructor(StringBuilder.class);
    String test = con.newInstance(new StringBuilder("argument for StringBuilder"));
    System.out.println(test.getClass().getName() + " : " + test);

    Constructor<?>[] consInteger = Integer.TYPE.getConstructors();
    System.out.println(consInteger + " / " + consInteger.length);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the output is:

```
[Ljava.lang.reflect.Constructor;@7852e922 / 15
java.lang.String : argument for StringBuilder
[Ljava.lang.reflect.Constructor;@4e25154f / 0
```

So, when I ask for the String class constructors I get an Array of 15 constructors. When I ask for Integer type constructors I get an Array of 0 elements (no constructors at all).

According to documentation Integer has 2 constructors (`Integer(int)` and `Integer(String)`).

What is the problem? How can I get a constructor for Integer type using reflection? When I try to use `Integer.TYPE.getConstructor(String.class)` I get a `NoSuchMethodException`.

Comment: Try out `getDeclaredConstructors` instead of `getConstructors` and probably you won't need the constructor. The `valueOf`method is more suitable for your task. And use Integer.class, instead of Integer.TYPE.class (see explanation by Joop)

Comment: Well, I am trying to achieve this in a generic class (T extends Number) that returns the result as an appropriate type depending on what the user of the class wants to get (the user passes the desired return type as Class argument to method). Unfortunately Number doesn't have "valueOf" method - they are defined by the subclasses (Integer, Float... etc)

Comment: `Number` is abstract - and every `T extends Number` has a `valueOf` method. Even `Character` and `Boolean` (which is not a number) has one. Maybe you misunderstand me. You will have to implement a factory method (as you already do) but instead of calling the constructor, you can call the `valueOf` factory method.

Comment: So you meant something like that:

`try {
   Method m = type.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
   output = (T) m.invoke(null, String.valueOf(input));
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
`

am I right?

Comment: I thought your problem was creating an `Integer` of an `int`? Instead of calling the constructor of Integer with an int value, you could call Integer.valueOf on the same int value with reflection. This is simpler because you need only the primitive value and the Wrapper can be derived generically.

Comment: No, maybe using Integer was misleading, I was thinking about any primitive wrapper that can hold a number.. Depending on what the user of class passes as argument to method(Integer.class or Float.class or whatever) it gets the result of that type.

eg. methodCall(Integer.class, String input) -> returns Integer
methodCall(Double.class, String input) -> returns Double,
and so on

Comment: This means that the purpose is not wrapping primitives to boxed types, i.e. int -> Integer, float -> Float, double -> Double. Now it sounds more like convert Strings to primitive wrapper types, i.e. String -> Integer, String -> Float, String -> Double. In this case the factory `parseXXX` would be more generic. Or do you plan to convert any primitive (and Strings) to wrapper types. This will not work generically with constructors because not all Wrapper types have constructors to all primitive types and String.

Comment: every numerical primitive wrapper (Byte, Short, Int, Long, Float, Double) has a constructor(String s) and valueOf(String s) methods. So it's possible to convert any primitive type to String and then to any wrapper Object as long as a) it isn't out of range of the wrapper b) we don't try to assign floating point to one of the integer types (we can cast floating point to an integer type first if that's something we really want)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Integer.TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE) is "The Class instance representing the primitive type `int`." `int` has no constructors.

Use `Integer.class` to refer to the wrapper class, which does.

Answer (score 3):

You need `Integer.class.getConstructors()`. Integer.TYPE == int.class.

However you might prefer Integer.valueOf. For the caching of Integers.